# How do I configure to use System.Web.UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm hoping to use something like the code put forward by MartinHN in the following post to create HTML formatted SMTP mail items: [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886728/generating-html-email-body-in-c-sharp)

Having problems creating a reference to the correct assemblies so that I can use the namespace "System.Web.UI.WebControls". the reference I'm trying to add is "System.Web" as suggested in [HERE](http://www.justskins.com/forums/add-reference-for-system-111523.html)

In the .NET section of my vis stud project's references I do not have System.Web:

[image]

If I browse my C-Drive and add a System.Web.dll file then I get the following:

[image]

How do I configure this project so that I'm able to use MailDefinition ?

Comment: Is your project setup to target the client profile versions of .NET?

Comment: alright Arran - just spotted this : [SO POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338205/missing-system-web-reference-in-asp-net) ...my is a console app - I've just changed and will see what happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change target framework from .NET client profile to .NET Framework 4 you shall be able to add system.web reference even in console Application.

Attached here are the Sreenshots from VS2012

[image]

[image]

Comment: @whytheq .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that is optimized for client applications. That is why system.web dll is not available.

Comment: I pretty much always accept answers but quite often I leave questions open for some time first - just in case anyone else wants to contribute. I can't imagine anyone else will be able to add any further value than your answer.